# How to make an javascript object to be called like a function?

Tags: javascript, function

I my case, I have a class, say

```
var Validator = function (...) {
    ...
};
Validator.prototype.validate = function(){...}
```

Now as the validate function is so important, I want to change the usage `validator.validate(...)` into `validator(...)`, here validator is an instance of Validator.
Is it possible and how to make it?

Comment: what is the problem with using validator.validate(…) ..?

Comment: Currently, [it's not possible](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Function_is_subclassable) to define a custom type so its instances are callable. The language standard has [specified that it should be supported](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-constructor), but engines haven't yet implemented it.

Comment: Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/jxnhqm64/1/  That other answer is okay, but I address a potential name/memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a reference to your instance method:

```
var validate = yourValidatorInstance.validate;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You would have to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the context: `var validate = yourValidatorInstance.validate.bind(yourValidatorInstance);`.

Comment: Yes right, lexical this would not be the same but I see no problem with using bind?

Comment: To make things simpler: `var validate = rebind(yourValidatorInstance, "validate"); function rebind(obj, name) { return obj[name].bind(obj); }`.

Comment: Yes I like this approach using underscore/lodash u could also use _.bind